# Throw customer error when partial view is missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view say Order.cshtml

This view has a partial view ConfirmationPartial.cshtml and within this partial view there is another partial view OrderDetailsPartial.cshtml

Now my question is I want to throw some kind of error in case **OrderDetailsPartial.cshtml** is missing on deployment server.

Comment: What is the mean by OrderDetailsPartial.cshtml missing?

Comment: it is a partial view within ConfirmationPartial view

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper method and call it from view to check if its exist or not

```
    public static HtmlString MyHelper(this HtmlHelper html)
    {
     var controllerContext = html.ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext;
     var result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(controllerContext, name, null);
     ...
    }
```